# Bring PHP actions into Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2016

I need some help.  What I need is actually very simple, but my unfamiliarity with Access makes this very difficult to bring into Access 2016.

I am looking for a way to streamline warrantable orders for vendor reimbursement.  at the moment I have an Access database with order information and I need to review supply orders for items which are supposed to be under warranty.   I am able to quickly put together a report based on the database in PHP, but I need to bring it into Access in a "reproducible" manner.

the output is roughly
store
    order# | order date | Qty ordered
    order# | order date | Qty ordered
    order# | order date | Qty ordered
next store
    order# | order date | Qty ordered
    order# | order date | Qty ordered
next store
    order# | order date | Qty ordered
    order# | order date | Qty ordered
    order# | order date | Qty ordered
next store
    order# | order date | Qty ordered

Right now the pseudo-php looks like this:

`<?php $db = "db connection information here"; 
$sql = "Select stores that have ordered in the last 30 days"
echo "<table>";
while (execute sql query here)
{echo $store;
$newsqlquery = "select order#, order date, qty ordered from table where >date()-365 and table.store = $store"
while (execute $newsqlquery)
{echo $order# $order date $qty}
}?>`

I'm trying to get this output into access, but I can't seem to make it work.  I've tried subqueries and reports, I'm wondering if the VBA in Access can make it work, but don't know how to make that happen either.

Comment: i think that most of the information that you posted sidetracks from the real question. i think that all you are asking `i would like to run a report in Access with the output having the following format`. if i am correct, please rephrase your question and remove the php tag

Comment: i do not have Access available, but i think that there is a report designer built into the program that allows you to produce the desired result

Comment: Thank you jsotola, I have removed the PHP tag to this post.  I do believe that I can achieve what I'm looking for with a report, but was hoping that someone would help me find how to run a while or "for each" loop in a report and pass the variable from the first query into the second query.